# Antonym of "comfort zone"

Tags: antonyms

What is a good antonym of "comfort zone", or an expression replacing "outside my comfort zone"? I'm writing an essay and don't want to repeat myself too much.

Comment: I wouldn’t use _comfort zone_ at all, other than with some degree of irony. It’s a cliché. Say exactly what you mean in your own words. What that will be depends on the context and the effect you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What @Barrie said. But in contexts where you *would* naturally use it, it's normally *outside **my** comfort zone*. Curiously, the first antonym that comes to mind for me is usually expressed as ***we're** in uncharted territory/waters*. Perhaps that's because we need other people more when we're in threatening/unknown situations.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I wondered about _uncharted territory_ myself.

Comment: @Barrie: It popped straight into my mind, but initially I dismissed it, thinking *comfort* and *knowledge* were different concepts. But then I remembered my old English teacher asking us class of 12-year-olds *"What's the one thing that **everyone** is most afraid of?"*. After five minutes of (some, quite revealing), suggestions from those brave enough to raise their hands, he finally put us out of our misery - *the **unknown!***.

Comment: Having had my answer down-voted just now, I want to take the opportunity (obviously belatedly) to refer you to my answer. If you feel it's a lousy answer, feel free to down-vote it; I won't be offended. Don

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say "pushes your personal boundaries" or "pushes the envelope." It doesn't necessarily mean that it is a bad thing, but it does imply that you are doing something that is difficult for you.

Comment: I like "push my personal boundaries". Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Colloquially, the opposite of one's comfort zone is one's danger zone.

Comment: Lots of hits for [discomfort zone](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=discomfort+zone&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest).

Comment: @tchrist: The top hits seem to be for Jonathan Franzen's play-on-words title.

Comment: "Discomfort zone" seems a better antonym than "danger zone". Just because one is not comfortable does not mean one is in danger.

Comment: Highway to the danger zone?

Answer (score 3):

How about "It makes me uncomfortable"? That's straightforward and seems to be what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Leon Festinger's concept of cognitive dissonance might help you.

When you are in your comfort zone, you are at ease and free of anxiety.  When you experience cognitive dissonance, you are ill-at-ease and anxious.  In other words, you've lost your equilibrium or homeostasis; you're out of your comfort zone. The following illustration is probably better than a thousand-word definition.

You arrive in Las Vegas with $500 in mad money in your pocket.  Before stepping into a casino, you swear to yourself that once the five-hundred is gone (of course, that will never happen, right?), you will quit and walk out of the casino.  A couple hours later, you've lost it all.  You are now out of your comfort zone.  What do you do?  Walk out? Perhaps, but perhaps not. You have just entered the realm of cognitive dissonance.  Why?  Because you are in the classic "on the one hand, but on the other hand" situation!

Since most folks find it difficult to hold two conflicting ideas in their minds at the same time without feeling this dissonance, they kind of weigh the alternatives, make a decision, and then convince themselves through the process of rationalization that they've make a good decision, one that restores their equilibrium and gets them back into their comfort zone.

The gambler in my illustration, who now is really stinging from having lost his mad money, probably has a little talk with himself, which might go as follows:

> "I swore to myself earlier to walk out if I lost the 500.  I'd better stick to the plan.  On the other hand, I feel so bad having lost that money, I've just got to get it back somehow.  Hmmm . . ..  I know, I'll get a little more money from the cash machine--just a hundred bucks and no more, and if I haven't gotten back the five hundred in the next hour, I'll definitely walk out then.  Yeah, that's the plan, and I'm stickin' to it!"

Before having this little talk with himself, our gambler experienced a swirl of emotions in his head:  regret, sadness, anger, frustration and shame, to mention just a few.  This swirl of emotions created dissonance, and to quell it, he made a decision. It may not have been the right decision, but it at least frees him up to do what he's decided to do--maybe.

The scenario could unfold in any number of ways once he re-enters the casino.  After losing 50 of his 100 bucks, he might have an epiphany and immediately storm out of the casino.  The inner conversation he has prior to his departure is likely short and sweet:  "That's it, I'll never gamble again!"

If, however, he stays until he's lost the hundred bucks, the situation might unfold as follows:  "Oh, brother, I've lost another hundred.  I know I said I'd leave if I lost the hundred, but I just KNOW I can pull ahead.  After all, I did win $200 a half hour ago, even though I lost it with another stupid bet.  I'll get just another hundred from the cash machine, and this time I'll really stick to my guns.  If I lose that, I'm outa' here." And so it goes.

Since many--if not most--folks can't tolerate the feeling that a decision they're making is at the same time both crazy AND sane, they convince themselves it's one or the other.  Sometimes the sane thing to do is cut their losses.  Even though it hurts in the short run, it saves them grief in the long run.  Sometimes, however, they refuse to cut their losses and forge ahead.  Why?  Because it's crazy NOT to!

Are we humans the rational critter or the rationalizing critter?  You be the judge.

I hope this long-winded answer is of some help.

Comment: I'm curious why someone just downvoted me, some four years after the fact! In re-reading my answer, I came to the conclusion that it's a pretty darn good one. Feeling comfortable and feeling dissonant are truly inimical to each other. My answer may be longwinded (no, it IS longwinded), but it contains some spot-on observations and conclusions. In fact, I think I'll draw the OP's attention to my answer (provided s/he is still a contributor, and provided s/he isn't the person who downvoted me!).

Answer (score 0):

How about *out of one's depth*?

The Free Dictionary:

> *out of one's depth*: involved in something that is beyond one's capabilities.
>
> *out of your depth*: knowing very little about a subject
>
> *be out of your depth*: to not have the knowledge, experience, or skills to deal with a particular subject or situation
>
> *out of one's depth* (also, *beyond one's depth*): outside one's understanding or competence; also see *over one's head*

To be *out of one's depth* is to be outside one's comfort zone.

Answer (score 0):

You could also say, "***not my cup of tea***".

TFD:

> **[not cup of tea](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+cup+of+tea)**
> Related to *not cup of tea*: *not my cup of tea*
>
> **not one's cup of tea**
> *Fig*. not one's choice or preference. (Used to describe an activity you do not enjoy. Can sound somewhat affected.)
> You three visit the
> museum without me. Looking at fussy old paintings is not my cup of
> tea.
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by
> The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.
>
> **not somebody's cup of tea**
> not what someone likes or is interested in
> I realize a fantasy computer game is not everyone's
> cup of tea, but this one is amazing.
>
> *Usage notes*: also used *without* not: I like suspense in movies. It's my cup of tea.
>
> Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms Copyright © Cambridge
> University Press 2003. Reproduced with permission.

Answer (score -1):

Make up a word, and add a hyphen.  I like "Un-comfort Zone" (rather than discomfort - which means something else). In fact, I was searching on the Internet for different words describing comfort zone, and came here.

Answer (score -1):

"[Hazard zone](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hazard)" is what I would call what is out of my comfort zone.